# Stuck in a Calculus exercise

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I'm studying for my exams coming up next week. The exercise is the following:

*Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a simply connected space of area equivalent to $2.$ Let $\gamma $ be a simple parametrization of $\delta \Omega$, where $\gamma (0) = (1,1)$ and $\gamma (1) = (1,0)$. Find:*

$$\int_0^1 (ye^{xy}, xe^{xy}) \, d\gamma$$

$$\int_{\delta \Omega} (x,3y) \,dS$$

By Green's Theorem, the seond integral should be 0 (right?). However, I haveno idea what to do about the first one. Since we're not integrating on the whole boundary of Omega, I have no idea what to do. I also don't know what I should do with the given information on Omega's area

Furthermore, the integrand's curl is not zero, so I can't just draw a line between $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$ and integrate over that.

Comment: the first one... is it conservative?  If it is, then there exist a function $G(x,y)$ such that $\nabla G = ye^{xy},xe^{xy}$  and the valuation of the integral only depends on the endpoints.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent to $2$"? If $\gamma$ parametrizes the boundary, then the values of $\gamma$ at the endpoints should be equal, and you've told us that its values at two point are not equal, so those are not the endpoints. What, then, are the endpoints? How do $x$ and $y$ depend on the variable that you've called $r$? What does your first integral have to do with $\Omega$ or its area? I find the question incomprehensible as stated.

Comment: We're not given the endpoints, we're only given two points of the boundary. Gamma's domain isn't $[0,1]$.

Comment: Also, as stated, the function is not conservative since its curl is not zero and is defined in a simply connected domain

Comment: $\nabla e^{xy} = y e^{xy}, xe^{xy}.$  So, your field is conservative.  You must have a mistake in your calculation of the curl.  Regarding the endpoints.  $\gamma (0) = (1,1)$ and $\gamma (1) = (1,0)$

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio : Might you have meant $d\gamma$ where you wrote $dr \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Ok, my bad. I just realized the function is in fact conservative. But I don't get the other part. Is it divergence theorem that I should use instead of Green's?